# JSON deserialization after property type changed

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I've been working on a C# program that serializes and deserializes some data in JSON format: however, now I have to radically change the type of a pre-existing property, from **string** to **Dictionary(string,string[])**.

Is there a way to make it so that, if the program tries to deserialize a document where the field is still a string, it performs some operations to convert it to a Dictionary? Or will the old documents become completely unusable?

For reference, the functions I've been using for reading/writing are the following:

Serialization:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, Formatting.Indented);
```

Deserialization:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(content);
```

**EDIT:**
As a simplified version of what I have to do, I have a class with a structure similar to this:

```
class ExampleClass // V1
{
    public string CustomProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And I need it, after the update, to look like this:

```
class ExampleClass // V2
{
    public Dictionary<string, string[]> CustomProperty { get; set; }
}
```

What I want is, if I try to deserialize a JSON with the V1 version of the class, instead of raising an exception, that string value will be used to populate the Dictionary (the basic plan is to put a default key and for the array the V1 value split by a default character: I doubt the exact details of the conversion would make much of a difference though). Afterwards, if I try to serialize the resulting object, it will only show the Dictionary, and not the original string.

Comment: Can you provide is with a simplified example of what you're trying to achieve?  It's easier to follow your needs if we have some code to work with.

Comment: I've added an example to the question, hopefully it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I've managed to solve the issue by explicitly writing the deserialization function, like this:

```
public static ExampleClass DeserializeData(string content)
    {
        try
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExampleClass>(content);
        }
        catch
        {
            // If it's in this section, it's trying to deconvert outdated JSON
            Dictionary<string, dynamic> objectMap = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(content);
            Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo> propertyMap = new Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo>();
            ExampleClass data = new ExampleClass();
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in typeof(ExampleClass).GetProperties())
                propertyMap.Add(property.Name, property);

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, dynamic> kvp in objectMap)
            {
                Type propertyType = propertyMap[kvp.Key].PropertyType;
                if (kvp.Key != "CustomProperty")
                {
                    if (kvp.Value is Array || kvp.Value is JArray)
                    {
                        Type recipientType = propertyType.GetElementType();
                        Type listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(recipientType);
                        System.Collections.IList itemList = (System.Collections.IList)Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
                        foreach (var item in (kvp.Value as JArray))
                            itemList.Add(Convert.ChangeType(item, recipientType));
                        Array itemArray = Array.CreateInstance(recipientType, itemList.Count);
                        itemList.CopyTo(itemArray, 0);
                        propertyMap[kvp.Key].SetValue(data, itemArray);
                    }
                    else if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyType) != null)
                    {
                        propertyMap[kvp.Key].SetValue(data, Convert.ChangeType(kvp.Value, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyType)));
                    }
                    else
                        propertyMap[kvp.Key].SetValue(data, Convert.ChangeType(kvp.Value, propertyType));
                }
                else
                {
                    if (kvp.Value is string)
                    {
                        propertyMap[kvp.Key].SetValue(data, new Dictionary<string, string[]>() { { "DEFAULT", (kvp.Value as string).Split('&') } });
                    }
                    else
                        propertyMap[kvp.Key].SetValue(data, kvp.Value);
                }
            }

            return data;
        }
    }
```

With this semi-generic function I can replicate the normal DeserializeObject, and have it elaborate the value depending on its type when it reaches a specific property: not only that, but by having it attempt to use DeserializeObject first, it ensures the fastest alternative is used on properly formatted JSON. It's probably not the most elegant solution, but it works, so I'll take it.

Thank you all for your answers, they were a great help in reaching this solution! Hope this helps others with the same issue as well!

Answer (score 0):

You could keep two versions of the class you are deserializing into, or you could use a [custom JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) and [`JsonConverterAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm#JsonConverterAttribute) to deal with the two different ways of deserializing your data.
Either way you choose, you will need some way of identifying what type of document or data type you have, and then you will need an `if` statement to switch to the appropriate deserialization method. The easiest way of determining this really depends on your situation.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways on how to handle such a contract change

1. Keep an old string property, create a new one with another name for the dictionary. Implement the lazy population for the dictionary property
2. Change the type of the existing property but create a new one and provide [JsonPropertyAttribute] with an old name. Implement the lazy population for the dictionary property
3. Use JsonConverterAttribute
4. Have multiple versions of the class (my preferred way)